# How do I access the current account environment variables from powershell?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, environment-variables

I am trying to track changes in my system as I install various programs. For example I have installed a few versions of python and kept checking my path variable which did not change. However my current account path did change. Without having admin rights a user can set environment variables for their account. How can I see these with powershell?

[image]

I'm looking for the User Variable Path highlighted in blue below, not the System variable named Path.

[image]

Comment: `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User')`

Comment: This is the .NET [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6k3c7b0) method. I don't think PowerShell provides a syntactically simpler alternative that allows specifying whether to get the machine, user, or process value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For user's environment variables, use this:

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables("User")
```

Use either of the following for system's environment variables:

```
gci env:*
ls Env:
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables("Machine")
```

For a particular variable:

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH","Machine")
```

Comment: That still just gives the system environment variables and the system path, not the current user's path variable which gets checked first.

Comment: That got it. Thanks.
 My final complete command was this.    
 [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH","User").split(';')

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Users\\Utente\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Utente\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Utente\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Utente\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32', 'C:\\Users\\Utente\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages']
>>>
```